# Exclude admin users from google analytics using segment

Tags: google-analytics

I want to exclude all our admin users using segments.  I figured the easiest way to do thsi would be to exclude anyone who has ever visited an admin page (anywhere under /admin/). Is there a way to set up a segment to exclude that group of uses.

I've been going through the options in the segmenting and filter but having found anything would exclude a user based on a single past action such as visiting a certain page.

Comment: yes, what have you tried?

Comment: Edited to ad what i have tried. (I would have though 3000rep would have saved me from being treated like a newbie)

Comment: Nope: every question is evaluated as per SO guidelines, regardless of rep score, no special treatment :)

Comment: Actually the question is not on topic for SO (since it is a reporting question, not a programming question).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Perhapss you're right, feel to migrate it over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is select the "Users" option, so GA will inspect ALL previous sessions and if any matches the condition, those users will be excluded:

[image]

And the below link explains differences in scope between users / sessions / hits:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123951?hl=en#filters

[image]